# Angular JS: how to change view in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I have navbar,sidebar and container. for each item in navbar have different sidebar. 

Ex: 
 - If i click Nav A, it have sidebar A, B, C. 
 - and if i click Nav B, it have sidebar D, E, F
 
 and for each sidebar have different data in container. anyone know how the logic for make that interface in angularjs.

Comment: Let's see an attempt at some code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to show different content based on which Nav is selected, you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="nav-controller">
    <ul data-ng-view>
        <li data-ng-click="showSidebar('a');">Sidebar A</li>
        <li data-ng-click="showSidebar('b');>Sidebar B</li>
    </ul>
    <ul data-ng-view="sidebar">
        {{sidebarContent}}
    <ul>
</div>
```

Javascript inside controller:

```
$scope.showSidebar = function(name){
    if(name == "a"){
        $scope.sidebarContent = "someCode for sidebar A";
    };
    if(name == "b"){
        $scope.sidebarContent = "someCode for sidebar B";
    };
};
```

Alternatively you could put the code in it's own template, and use the following:

HTML:

```
    <div data-ng-include="{{sidebarContentUrl}}"></div>
```

Javascript inside controller:

```
$scope.showSidebar = function(name){
    if(name == "a"){
        $scope.sidebarContentUrl = "partials/sidebarA.tpl.html";
    };
    if(name == "a"){
        $scope.sidebarContentUrl = "partials/sidebarB.tpl.html";
    };
};
```

You could also include all the sidebars in one template, and hide them conditionally.